# WAMP and IIS conflict after changing the port number to 9999?

Tags: iis, phpmyadmin, wamp, conflict

I tried to work with WAMP, and as port 80 is already used by IIS, I changed the port number to 9999.

I am accessing using `localhost:9999` but the problem is, I can't access MySQL or phpmyadmin.

Comment: are you getting an error, if so, what.